Distribution inequality $\langle\Delta|u|,\varphi\rangle\geq\langle\Delta u\cdot\text{sign}(u),\varphi\rangle$ for non-negative $\varphi\in\mathcal D$

Suppose $u \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a real-valued function, and define the sign function $\operatorname{sign}(u)$ as
$$
   \operatorname{sign}(u)(x) = \begin{cases}
       1, & u(x) > 0; \\
       0, & u(x) = 0; \\
       -1, & u(x) < 0.
   \end{cases}
   $$
Prove, in the sense of distributions that
$$
   \Delta |u| \overset{\mathcal{D}'}{\geq} \Delta u \cdot \operatorname{sign}(u),
   $$
i.e., for any non-negative real-valued function $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$,
$$
   \langle \Delta |u|, \varphi \rangle \geq \langle \Delta u \cdot \operatorname{sign}(u), \varphi \rangle,
   $$

I don't quite know how to deal with $\Delta|u|$. So I cannot compute it "by force". Someone said that I can approximate $u$ in the sense of distributions with $\sqrt{u^2 + \varepsilon^2}$. But I think I don't realize the main step.

Hint: $\langle \Delta |u|,\varphi\rangle=\langle |u|,\Delta \varphi\rangle$

@NicoZimmer, yes but the key part is "$|u|$" which I can't deal with well.

@TaD what is the source of these exercises on distributions?

I am also interested in the source of these exercises

@SineoftheTime, they are all in the mathematical analysis lecture notes by Pin Yu, who is a professor in Tsinghua University. But actually, the content are all Chinese. Maybe you can't find it if you search in English. If you can read Chinese, you can look through the lecture note pdf: https://github.com/asukaminato0721/good-books/blob/master/%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90%E4%B9%8B%E8%AF%BE%E7%A8%8B%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89Analysis123.pdf. And you can also read them from website https://www.bananaspace.org/wiki/%E8%AE%B2%E4%B9%89:%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90.

@whpowell96, see above

@SineoftheTime, anyway, do you mind trying this exercise which haven't been solved now? math.stackexchange.com/q/4997594/1084278

@SineoftheTime, By the way, if you don't understand Chinese well---distribution's content is in the part of Analysis 3, which is from section 58. And you can search for "作业" (word "homework" in Chinese), then use some program or just use chatgpt to get the tex code of some pages so that you can translate them to English (or your native language) easily (for example, you can use chatgpt again).

@TaD thank you for the links!!

Observe that if $u_n \overset{\mathcal{D}'}{\geq} v_n$ and $u_n \to u$ and $v_n \to v$ then $u \overset{\mathcal{D}'}{\geq} v$ for distributions $u_n,u,v_n,v$.
Now, calculate
$$\Delta\sqrt{u^2 + \varepsilon^2} = \frac{u\Delta u}{\sqrt{u^2+\varepsilon^2}} + \frac{\varepsilon^2|\nabla u|^2}{\sqrt{u^2+\varepsilon^2}^3} \geq (\Delta u)\cdot \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+\varepsilon^2}}.$$
In $\mathcal{D}'$ it holds
$$\sqrt{u^2 + \varepsilon^2} \to |u| \text{ and } \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+\varepsilon^2}} \to \text{sign}(u) \text{ for } \varepsilon \to 0.$$
So, taking the limit for $\varepsilon \to 0$ in the above inequality in $\mathcal{D}'$ it follows
$$\Delta |u| \overset{\mathcal{D}'}{\geq} (\Delta u)\cdot\text{sign}(u).$$
